# show toast using CSS, JS and asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, toast

I have a toast.js file which contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tstInfo").on("click",function(){
       $.toast({
        heading: 'Welcome to my Elite admin',
        text: 'Use the predefined ones, or specify a custom position object.',
        position: 'top-right',
        loaderBg:'#ff6849',
        icon: 'info',
        hideAfter: 3000, 
        stack: 6
      });

 });});
```

on my aspx page i have button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="tstInfo btn-primary" OnClick="btnShow_Click" />
```

now i want to call js function when i click on the button. can somebody please tell me how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="tstInfo btn-primary" OnClick="btnShow_Click" />
```

in your code replace btnShow with `tstInfo` it will work and remove OnClick

Comment: i want to show it from code behind not aspx page but .cs page

Comment: your question is unclear @saif . What do you want to show from code behind? Trigger the js function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnClientClick` like this :

`OnClientClick="javascript:alert('Hello')"`